# Don't understand how to make a trial license to my windows 8 store app

Tags: visual-c++, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I'm developing an app, everything is done, but I want to make it free with some limitation, to make users purchase a full version. There is a good tutorial on Windows DEV for C#, but I don't understand how to do it in C++. I understood that I have to use CurrentAppSimulator to simulate this thing.

So, for example, I want to do an experiment: I have an app with two TextBlocks: if I have trial version I want to see only TextBlock1, if I have full version, I want to see also the second one. Then I want a button to change from trial version and full version. How can I implement such an easy thing?